# Firebase stopped reporting in_app_purchase events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

On June 12th firebase console stopped reporting the automatically tracked in_app_purchase event for several of our apps (across multiple projects). Our projects are linked with GPC as required and the tracking used to work reliably prior to June 12th. It should not be an issue in the app as it happened for multiple apps independently and moreover we have at least one app where the tracking still works.

Has anyone encountered similar issue and knows how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any recent outages in Analytics on https://status.firebase.google.com/. Given this information there's not a lot anyone here can do. I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's little anyone can answer here and this problem seems better suited for Firebase support.

Comment: I tried that already few days ago. But i agree that most likely there is not much anyone can do. Still, i think it's worth the try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We encountered the same issue and approached Firebase Support. They answered quickly (within a couple of hours!), so I'll share their response:
"Subscriptions are not automatically tracked by Firebase. See [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) page for more information.

The reason why you're seeing the in_app_purchase previously is due to a bug on our end, and it got fixed last June 13.

Apologies for any inconvenience this might've caused you."

Possible workarounds could be manually reporting an event upon purchase or using the Google Play Revenue dashboard and subscription graphs.

Comment: Finally got an answer from Firebase support and they indeed confirmed this is the reason. Moreover, they also said they are working on automatically logging subscription based events by Android. Unfortunately, they do not wish to commit to any ETA.

Comment: @ira do you have maybe some updated information from Firebase about subscription based events?

Comment: can we add that event manually if the payment is not from in_app_purachase?